# Different Account page layout for mobile view and LEX

Tags: mobile, lightning-record-page

I have a requirement where in I have to show a quick action on account page only on mobile. But per my understanding, we have a common section on page layout for Lightning and mobile. So what is visible on LEX will be visible in mobile. I was going through salesforce release note and found something interesting about different form factor for phone and desktop. However, I am not sure whether this is something which will resolve my issue or not.Any idea how to achieve this using OOTB functionalities?

[Release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_mobile_for_all.htm)